# How to add HTML tags around a variable if it contains a value from an array, and leave it as it is if it doesn't in Smarty?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

In Smarty, I have this variable:

`{assign var=newNAME value='SNMS Stros Mos KOP2 APC'}`

I have the following array:

`{$spec_array = ['Stros Mos', 'Monk Dup', 'Lip Mok']}`

I need to check if 'Stros Mos' in `$newNAME` is in the array. In my searches for "how to check if a string contains a value from an array", I found that you could loop through the array. In this case, the condition is: "if the value is contained within the array add `<i></i>` around it, if not leave it as it is". This is what I came up with:

```
{foreach from=$spec_array item=spec}
        {if $newNAME|strpos:$spec}
        <span class="thumbName">{$newNAME|replace:$spec:"<i>$spec</i>" nofilter}</span>
        {else}
        <span class="thumbName">{$newNAME}</span>
        {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

The problem is that it outputs 3 `<span>`, as such:

```
SNMS <i>Stros Mos</i> KOP2 APC
SNMS Stros Mos KOP2 APC
SNMS Stros Mos KOP2 APC
```

I understand why: it's because the items from the array are being looped, and if the condition is met - add italics around the value, if not just print it as it is. Because there are 3 values in the array I get 3 outputs. I only need the first output. `$newNAME` could be anything, and sometimes it will not contain any of the values from `$spec_array`. I feel like the foreach loop here doesn't work. I understand that this is a logical problem more than a coding problem, but I am really new at PHP and Smarty and I am not a great thinker. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use new variable and break loop if found match. Also, condition `$newNAME|strpos:$spec !== false` is better (if you allow to search string in "0" position of text).

```
    {foreach $spec_array as $spec}
        {if $newNAME|strpos:$spec !== false}
            {assign var=newNAME_parsed value=$newNAME|replace:$spec:"<i>$spec</i>"}
            {break}
        {else}
            {assign var=newNAME_parsed value=$newNAME}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}

<span class="thumbName">{$newNAME_parsed nofilter}</span>
```